# Guide me in understanding the logic used in SQL query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(purchaser_id, '[a-z]') IS NOT NULL 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE purchaser_id 
    END AS s_purchaser_id
FROM 
    table1;
```

Does this mean if there is any alpha-numeric value it will replace to NULL?

Thanks!

Comment: aphanumeric means there can be numbers, but yout pattern has only a-z, so that means if it has small letters it shows NULL. Besides make a taböe and test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic says that if a `purchaser_id` contain a lowercase letter, the `s_purchaser_id` output will be `NULL`, otherwise the output will be just be the same `purchaser_id`.

Some samples:

```
purchaser_id | s_purchaser_id
ABC          | ABC
abc          | NULL
ABCabc       | NULL
```